# Move multi-line text element

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to move the following multi-line text element:

```
<text x="80" y="187.5" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#ffffff" fill="#ffffff" font-weight="bold" id="selector" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal; ">
    <tspan dy="-13.203125" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Line 1</tspan>
    <tspan dy="19.2" x="80" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Line 2</tspan>
    <tspan dy="19.2" x="80" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Line 3</tspan>
</text>
```

I use the following code to move the text:

```
var tTargetDesc = d3.select("#selector").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return width / 16;
    });
```

But only the first line is moved. Do I have to move every tspan one by one?

Comment: Have you tried using transform/translate instead of modifying the coordinates directly?

Comment: Thanks! I have used transform attribute and it works.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you use the `transform` attribute instead:

```
var tTargetDesc = d3.select("#selector").transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate(" + (width / 16) + ",0)";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate wasn't working for me because of the coordinate space thing.. Here is what I ended up doing

```
 var children = txtElement.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var textChild = children[i];           
        textChild.setAttribute("x", _X);

    }
```